# Is there any way to know which peer disconnected the call Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am trying to collect some info about the ongoing call in asterisk but during hangup I want to log which peer initiated the process of hangup. I am new to asterisk so I have no idea if its possible or not. Please help me if it can be done. I have tried to use HANGUPCAUSE_KEYS but it does not provide much information.

Actually I want to know who has released the line first? If A and B are connected with bridge and B releases I want to record that B has released the channel and vice versa. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 ways.
1) Set a Hangup Handler in your dialplan (extensions.conf). Maybe it is the easiest way, but limited. [WIKI: Hangup Handler](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Handlers)
2) Use AMI and try to monitor the channels. It can be complicated, but almost limitless and powerful. [WIKI: Asterisk AMI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239)

Comment: thanks @Tamas but I don't find handlers useful too because I do not get to know who released the channel caller or callee?

Comment: So... The Dial application's 'g', 'G' or 'F' options can be helpful.
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial